# "The value in Date is not a valid date" error

Tags: datetime

I am editing an existing node of content type event, and am trying to update the Date using the date pop up. However, no matter what date I select I get the The value in

> "Date is not a valid date"

error.

The same issue appears when I try and add a new node with the same content type...

Any suggestions?

Comment: please expand details

Comment: Event when we declare one field is Date type but there are several kinds of Date : Date, Date(ISO format), Date(Unix timestamp). Maybe you should change to another types to test. For me. I got the painful experience in contest module for this problem.

Comment: As everyone said, the date pop is submitting different format of date and the date field is expecting different format. However by default the popup should work unless you did any changes. Can you please provide more information on which popup plugin you're using

Comment: Thanks @Mathankumar

This is the one I am using:
name = Date Popup
description = Enables jquery popup calendars and time entry widgets for selecting dates and times.
dependencies[] = date_api
package = Date/Time
core = 7.x
configure = admin/config/date/date_popup

stylesheets[all][] = themes/datepicker.1.7.css

; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2012-08-13
version = "7.x-2.6"
core = "7.x"
project = "date"
datestamp = "1344850024"

Answer (score 1):

The latest dev version of clientside validation contains a fix to support more formats, so you can give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I found that this error is definitely tied directly to the date popup widget.  As a quick fix try changing your fields' widget type to **select list**.

Comment: You are right @squarecandy
Changing the widget tpe to select list work. What do I need to do to fix the pop up widget?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1241254) tied to the date string formats you defined. As in the issue, changing the 'short' format definition from **dd.mm.YYYY** to the php date() string format of **d.m.Y** appears to have corrected the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Triskelion

My settings are as follows:

Manage fields
More settings and values
Date entry
Date entry options 
02/04/2013 - 9:40:59pm

Manage display
Short (02/04/2013 - 9:39pm)

However, I am still getting the "The value in Date is not a valid date." error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Clientside Validation module disable it.